# xPlace EditText over fixed points on background image for different resulution

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building layers in `Android`, for that I'm loading an background image into `ImageView` with a small mini black boxes drawn over it, like placeholders.

I was wonder how can I set some `EditText` over those small mini points on the image,you cant see them but suppose I have to black box'x over the bg image and I want to place over them my `text1`,`text2`. I tried using `RelativeLayout` and using fixed padding but when changing the screen size or orientation it get messy, I read that the best thing is to place them on run time by checking the screen resolution and calculating the right sizes for each `EditText`, but it is to much work I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Image, and I want to put some text on the black boxes of the result and the team.
[image]

What options do I have?

Comment: please share your xml file

Comment: does your background image changes??

Comment: @user3676184 I added the layout

Comment: @Crazy No the background not change,only the text over it in EditText

Comment: @Alex Opent thank you for sharing code. Now tell me your black box image size means its occupying whole screen or its half screen. Or just do one thing send me static screen shot of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of device size variation in Android you can't get perfection by doing this, I would recommend you to use plain background of image and take that small mini boxes as different image and set it as a `EditText` background.

other wise you have to manually set the padding and margin for every devices in which you getting differences.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I added image where I want to place the text, I d'ont want setting it for each device, I'm looking for a way doing it on real time in a generic mode

Comment: @AlexOpent I would recommend you to take one complete background of blackbox  and take other images in slicing and set it as a images in Linear Layout or Relative layout whichever is convinient.